# Does time to live (ttl) affect or decrease performance?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

i am using cassandra and using ttl (time to live) in queries for auto delete rows. My question is that, is TTL affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't affect the performance in a measurable way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally use of a `TTL` makes little to no difference in the performance (i.e. response time) of CQL queries.

It is worth nothing, however, that use of the optional `TTL` value when inserting or updating a record requires additional storage than the same record without a `TTL`. This can become relevant if/when you are creating many records with long TTL periods.

You can learn more about estimating the size of records stored in Cassandra here:

- [Introduction to Cassandra 3 Storage Engine](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/03/04/introductiont-to-the-apache-cassandra-3-storage-engine.html)
- [Calculate the size of a Cassandra Table](https://shermandigital.com/blog/calculate-the-size-of-a-cassandra-table/)